# Android Stretching Images in NetworkImageView XML

Tags: android, xml, image, android-volley, networkimageview

I'm trying to figure out how to get TV banners from TheTVDB (example http://thetvdb.com/banners/graphical/84947-g6.jpg) to fit the screen width.  This gets me the there but I don't want to have the white space from setting the margin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
        android:id="@+id/poster"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However if I remove the `android:layout_margin="8dp"` I suddenly just get half of the first banner loaded but none of the others appear.

I've tried setting it the `width` and/or `height` to `wrap_content` and removing the `margin` and `scaleType`, that works fine, but the banners do not stretch across the screen.

Comment: Have you tried setting width to "match_parent" and height to "wrap_content"?

Comment: Yes, I've tried setting them both and also one or the other. It puts them all in when I do that but doesn't stretch them across. EDIT: if I do set it the way you mention it only displays half of the first banner and nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26874926/scaled-images-with-volley) was very helpful.  His solution at the end to programaticly get the width of the screen from WindowManager was very helpful.

Ended up doing mine like so:

```
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
final int width;
if (version >= 13) {
    Point size = new Point();
    mDisplay.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
} else {
    width = mDisplay.getWidth();
}
myPoster.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, 199));
```